# C# .Net 4.8 Webview2 How can I get html source code?

Tags: facebook, webview2

```
string url="https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=861918397618775&set=ecnf.100000266187355";
webView2FB.Source = new Uri(url);

string pageSource = await webView2FB.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

The program gets stuck at this line: "`string pageSource = await webView2FB.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");`". What could be the reason?

I'm trying to retrieve the webpage source code as I want to quickly download photos.

I've noticed that if I'm logged into Facebook, the program gets stuck indefinitely, but if I'm not logged in, the program completes quickly. However, some photos are restricted (only accessible by friends), so I need to be logged in.

Comment: If you run under the debugger do you see any error messages or exceptions? When under the debugger can you break in and see where the code is stuck?